# Magento 2 : Fresh magento 2 API not working?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I have installed fresh magento 2 and when I hit API of anything it doesn't work for me.

Check this url : [visit here](http://3.19.27.223/magento2/rest/v1/)

It seems like an permission issue and I can't figure out what? If anyone having knows about this, please let me know.

**EDIT :**

```
routes.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd"> 
  <router id="standard"> <route id="mobileapp" frontName="mobileapp"> 
  <module name="Vendor_App" /> 
  </route> </router> 
</config>

webapi.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route method="POST" url="/V1/signin/">
    <service class="Vendor\App\Api\LoginManagementInterface" method="setSignin"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
</routes>
```

Comment: which API you want to access ?

Comment: If I rename mywebapi xml then it shows as 404 and am accessing custom api

Comment: Ok. Did you write anywhere "get" string in your file ?

Comment: Please add your route url of API here.

Comment: @Aaditya updated

Comment: As per your code preference is missing in di.xml

Comment: <preference for="Commerceshop\MobileApp\Api\LoginManagementInterface" type="Commerceshop\MobileApp\Model\LoginManagement"/>

Comment: Should be like this, based on your MODEL file name which is extending Interface

Comment: It there already mate @Aaditya

Comment: Okay bro, Are you using POSTMAN for testing this API ?

Comment: Yes ofcourse but this error keep on coming am not much aware of api and code even not writter by me